# Bash: grep multiple items in a file loop

Tags: bash, file, shell, scripting, grep

I'm trying to write a Bash script that finds the occurrence of multiple items in a file, in one loop. This is a small piece of the file I'm trying to read:

```
112/14-13:21:18 - write(FD 1) = 82 bytes
112/14-13:21:18 - read(FD 0, 16384 bytes buffer) = 146 bytes
112/14-13:21:18 - unlink(/data/547/07/17/nmsa000000000005/archives/9589fecf-779b-4fc3-8bb3-4cd6b1932d19/ar16f8888285fb4989b817589b0219d08b) = 0
112/14-13:21:18 - __xstat64(1, /data/547/07/17/nmsa000000000005/archives/9589fecf-779b-4fc3-8bb3-4cd6b1932d19/ar16f8888285fb4989b817589b0219d08b, ...) = 0
112/14-13:21:18 - write(FD 1) = 86 bytes
112/14-13:21:18 - read(FD 0, 16384 bytes buffer) = 138 bytes
```

What I want is that I can display how many times there's a "read" and a "write" and how long it took.

Currently I've got this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

READ=0
WRITE=0

while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]
do
    READ=$(grep -c 'read(')
    WRITE=$(grep -c 'write')
done < $1

echo "Read $READ times"
echo "Wrote $WRITE times"
```

But I'm receiving this output on a small testfile:

```
Read 20 times
Wrote 0 times
```

The script doesn't seem to count the number of times "write" is in the input file.

I'm new to Bash and it's my first script. Can anyone help or tell what I'm doing wrong? And how can I implement the time part of the script?
Also, can this script be optimized since the input will be quite large (+10GB file)?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Extra second of data

```
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Reverse/Common.php, ...) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - open(/usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Reverse/Common.php, 0) = FD 8
112/14-13:21:17 - close(FD 8) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/local/lib/php/MDB2/Driver/Manager/pgsql.php, ...) = -1
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Manager/pgsql.php, ...) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Manager, ...) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - open(/usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Manager/pgsql.php, 0) = FD 8
112/14-13:21:17 - close(FD 8) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/local/lib/php/MDB2/Driver/Manager/Common.php, ...) = -1
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Manager/Common.php, ...) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - open(/usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Manager/Common.php, 0) = FD 8
112/14-13:21:17 - close(FD 8) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/local/lib/php/MDB2/Driver/Datatype/pgsql.php, ...) = -1
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Datatype/pgsql.php, ...) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Datatype, ...) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - open(/usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Datatype/pgsql.php, 0) = FD 8
112/14-13:21:17 - close(FD 8) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/local/lib/php/MDB2/Driver/Datatype/Common.php, ...) = -1
112/14-13:21:17 - __lxstat(1, /usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Datatype/Common.php, ...) = 0
112/14-13:21:17 - open(/usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/Datatype/Common.php, 0) = FD 8
112/14-13:21:17 - close(FD 8) = 0
```

Comment: Why not `grep` the file?  Why do you need to loop over every line?

Comment: @devnull Because I just want the file to be read once. The input file will be +10GB. Or will this not infect performance?

Comment: What makes you think that using a loop to read _line by line_ would be any better than `grep`ping it in one go?

Comment: @devnull Won't the file be read twice instead of once?

Comment: I guess that it'd still be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try `awk` then you'll only need one pass over the file during which you can count both reads and writes:

```
awk '/write\(/{w++;next}  /read\(/{r++;next}  END{print "Read: ",r, "Write: ",w}' file
Read:  2 Write:  2
```

That says... every time you find a line with `write(` in it, increment `w`. Every time you find a line with `read(` in it, increment `r`. At the end, print `r` and `w`.

If you want the number of times each second, you can use this:

```
awk 'FNR==1{r=0;w=0;lasttime=$1} $1!=lasttime{print lasttime,"Read: ",r, "Write: ",w;r=0;w=0;lasttime=$1} /write\(/{w++} /read\(/{r++}' file
```

Basically, it outputs the count of reads and writes every time the second changes.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information but I'd rather stick to bash. Unless you can add the time part really quickly.

Comment: That's pretty easy if you give us more than 1 second of data!

Comment: I have updated it to output the totals every time the seconds change.

Comment: Mmmm, the extra second of data you have supplied contains no reads and no writes!

Comment: I know. It's possible that there aren't any reads or writes that second. If that's the case, can it output a 0?

Comment: Sure, I now initialise `r` and `w` in the BEGIN section - see amended answer.

Comment: Thee was a bug, please copy my answer again, as it has been amended.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you loop ?

This script work fine :

```
#!/bin/bash
READ=$(grep -c 'read(' $1)
WRITE=$(grep -c 'write(' $1)
echo "Read $READ times"
echo "Wrote $WRITE times"
```

Comment: It does! But won't it be slow when the input file is +10GB, since the file will be grepped twice?

Comment: Yeah it will be slow but there is nothing to do. The only thing you can do is using fgrep instead of grep (you're using fixed string). And you can also use parallel if you are on a multi-core architecture.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you pass all the data inside the file `$1` to the stdin of the while loop. Your initial `read` command consumes the first line of this data, then the first `grep` command consumes the remainder. This leaves no data left for the second `grep` command, and hence it does not return anything. As a side-effect, if the first line of the file contains `read(`, it will not be counted by `grep` as it has already been consumed by `read`. Your script can be improved thus (similar to @John's answer):

```
#!/bin/bash

READ=$(grep -c 'read(' "$1")
WRITE=$(grep -c 'write' "$1")
echo "Read ${READ:-0} times"
echo "Wrote ${WRITE:-0} times"
```

Comment: What about the time part? The first part of the line includes a timestamp. I'd like to know how many times each command was executed each second. Is that possible? Or per minute?

Answer (score 0):

As the OP is concerned about reading the file twice, so this could be done:

```
#!/bin/bash
R=0
W=0
while read -r line
do
        R=$((  $(grep -c 'read('  <<< "$line" )  + R ))
        W=$((  $(grep -c 'write(' <<< "$line" )  + W ))
done

printf "Read  %i times\n" $R
printf "Wrote %i times\n" $W
```

Cheers,

Paul

Comment: What about the time part? The first part of the line includes a timestamp. I'd like to know how many times each command was executed each second. Is that possible? Or per minute?